# Google Geocode/Places API: search zip code - get addresses connected to it, possible?

Tags: autocomplete, google-api, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api, geocode

So, another Google API question but I didn't find any threads for my needs.
I'm trying to implement a basic zip code search with Google API in plain Javascript (tested both Geocode and Places with Autocomplete).
User should be able to search on a specific zip code and get street names returned which are connected to that zip code (and simply choose the correct address).

I have no problems getting results back using either one of the APIs but I can't wrap my head around Googles documentation for it since nothing tells you if this is possible or not.
I've tested a couple of different types to send in the options setting but none actually returns an array of addresses.

Been thinking if reverse geocoding would be a solution but seems a bit hacky and also would require multiple requests..

Simply out of ideas, any help appreciated.

```
  types: ['geocode'],
  componentRestrictions: { country: 'SE' }
}

let autocomplete;

function initialize() {
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  document.getElementById('postalCode'), options);
  autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': ['SE']})
  autocomplete.setFields(['address_component']);
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that it is currently not supported for the Geocoding or Places API to show a list of addresses by zip code.

Places Autocomplete is designed to return place predictions based on the user input and perceived relevance. While the Geocoding API is designed to convert a single string address to coordinates and vice versa.

You can use this [Geocoder tool](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/) to test this.

There is also a related feature request for this functionality, it's marked as Infeasible/Intended behavior but you can still star it to receive updates:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64769088

Starring the issue also provides valuable feedback on the importance of the issue to customers, and increases the issue's priority with the product engineering team.

Comment: Google won't implement open feature requests that have been starred by hundreds of people, sometimes over many years. So you tell me what's the point starring a FR that's already marked as "won't fix"... This is a typical "official Google answer".

Comment: @MrUpsidown Seems you think Google are ignoring hundreds of people for many years,  and your conclusion is that this means we should not bother trying to make them listen or  maybe change anything ever. I think both the question and answer here are useful and well written.

Comment: @MemeDeveloper No. What I meant is that there are *some open feature requests* that have been starred by hundreds of people and that have never been implemented in years (and probably will never be). So I see very little point instructing someone to star an issue that is **already closed** and that has been starred by only 1 person so far.

Comment: @MrUpsidown you have a point, I just think that "every little helps" and there's no harm in us trying our best to let the giants like Google / MS / Apple know about what we think we need and want... whether they respond well is another question.

Comment: My initial comment was only about the answer above which was provided by a user who once claimed on their profile that they were a Google employee and I thought it wasn't the best advice to instruct someone to star a closed issue in their tracker when there are, as I said, other issues with hundreds of stars that are open since several years (over 12 years for some of them...) and that have never been implemented so far. Obvioulsy, you are free to star it or even to open a new one (which in this case might be more clever).